# I can't create app using "npx create-react-app my-app"

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

##### I'm trying to create a react app with "npx create-react-app my-app" but I'm getting this error.

```
PS C:\Users\m.saral\Desktop\app> npx create-react-app my-app

Creating a new React app in C:\Users\m.saral\Desktop\app\my-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...


Aborting installation.
Error: spawn UNKNOWN
    at ChildProcess.spawn (node:internal/child_process:420:11)
    at Object.spawn (node:child_process:733:9)
    at spawn (C:\Users\m.saral\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\cross-spawn\index.js:12:24)
    at C:\Users\m.saral\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:383:19
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at install (C:\Users\m.saral\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:334:10)
    at C:\Users\m.saral\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:461:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  errno: -4094,
  code: 'UNKNOWN',
  syscall: 'spawn'

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting my-app/ from C:\Users\m.saral\Desktop\app
Done.
```

```
PS C:\Users\m.saral\Desktop\app> node -v
v16.18.0
```

###### I tried running command prompt as administrator

###### I tried:

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
npm uninstall create-react-app

I deleted and reinstalled Nodejs

npm install npm@latest -g
```

###### Node Version: v16.18.0

Npm Version: 8.19.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Problem solved

**I could not find why the problem was solved when trying randomly**

```
PS C:\Users\m.saral\Desktop\app\my-app> npm -v
8.19.2
```

```
PS C:\Users\m.saral\Desktop\app\my-app> npx -v
8.19.2
```

```
PS C:\Users\m.saral\Desktop\app\my-app> node -v
v16.18.0
```

```
PS C:\Users\m.saral\Desktop\app\my-app> npm -g list
C:\Users\m.saral\AppData\Roaming\npm
├── create-react-app@5.0.1
├── npm@8.19.2
└── tar@2.0.0
```

```
PS C:\Users\m.saral\Desktop\app> npx create-react-app my-app              

Creating a new React app in C:\Users\m.saral\Desktop\app\my-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...


added 1392 packages in 1m

212 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details        

Initialized a git repository.

Installing template dependencies using npm...

added 56 packages in 6s

212 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
Removing template package using npm...


removed 1 package, and audited 1448 packages in 2s

212 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

9 high severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.

Created git commit.

Success! Created my-app at C:\Users\m.saral\Desktop\app\my-app
Inside that directory, you can run several commands:

  npm start

  npm run build
    Bundles the app into static files for production.

  npm test
    Starts the test runner.

  npm run eject
    Removes this tool and copies build dependencies, configuration files
    and scripts into the app directory. If you do this, you can’t go back!
We suggest that you begin by typing:

  cd my-app
  npm start

Happy hacking!
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try with the Latest nodejs Version For Window https://nodejs.org/en/

Also check npm Version as WEll